# Query Email from linked Task list to create Email Appointment

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, query

i've reached a dead end with linked lists in SharePoint Online: I created two Lists "Tasks" and "Data". The Data list has a unique Identifier (ID-Number) that is used by tasks to connect tasks (often up to 20 tasks per data element) to data elements.

I would like to write a Workflow (or script) to query all persons who are asigned to a task, related to a specific data element and create an outlook meeting invitation email with these persons as recipients.

Has anybody here done something similar? I'd apreciate your help! Thanks, LS

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution:

1. Custom action that opens a popup by passing the id of selected task List item
2. The popup opens an application page. using script or code behind you retrieve all the tasks related by data id.
3. And then  get the Assigned To for each task and include them to your meeting
4. For the meeting you can export an ICS file. using api like ics.js